# iis 6: Unable to assign IP address to new website

Tags: iis-6, website

I am trying to create a new website in IIS 6. I follow the wizard and choose an IP address after pinging it and ensuring it does not return a reply. After adding the site with the new IP address and pinging it the ip still returns nothing. The website also does not load using this IP in a browser. What am I missing?

Comment: did you just 'randomly' pick an IP? ;)  Or was it assigned to your INTERFACE & box already? Hmm...

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I did. I knew that something was missing but couldn't put my finger on it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IP address has to be one of the addresses physically assigned to the server IIS is running on in the TCP/IP settings.  You can't just arbitrarily pick an IP address that nothing is using.

Answer (score 2):

Where to start:

Is the ip address bound to the NIC?

Is the NIC plugged in to the network?

Is the web site bound to the ip address?

Is the web site running?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just 'picked' an IP address out of thin air and pinged it and assumed it gets assigned to IIS.

Why not use a virtual host approach (you assign it a dns like mydomain.com).

Your server will stay on 1 single IP (which is what it most likely has, as I would find it odd to get an IP per website for IIS).

This is the proper way to get it done when adding new sites to IIS (unless you really do have IP's lying around *pointed* to the server -- properly!).

Comment: I also think your method is the best way to do it, however this is the way we do it where I work. I am not sure why.

Comment: I would suggest investigating WHY they don't run virtual host setups. It seems odd.